# Error (Setting objectives in 'params' and 'obj' at the same time is not allowed) in xgboost() function in R

Tags: r, xgboost

Below is the code which i am executing on XGBOOST,

```
data(Glass, package = "mlbench")

levels(Glass$Type) <- c(0:5) #Proper Sequence. Should start with 0

Glass$Type <- as.integer(as.character(Glass$Type))

set.seed(100)
options(scipen = 999)


library(caret)
R_index <- createDataPartition(Glass$Type, p=.7, list = FALSE)
gl_train <- Glass[R_index,]
gl_test <- Glass[-R_index,]


'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')

library(xgboost)
library(Matrix)

#Creating the matrix for training the model
train_gl <- xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(gl_train[ ,colnames(gl_train) %ni% 'Type']),
                        label = as.numeric(gl_train$Type))

test_gl <- xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(gl_test[ ,colnames(gl_test) %ni% 'Type']))

watchlist <- list(train = gl_train, test = gl_test)


#Define the parameters and cross validate
param <- list("objective" = "multi:softmax",
              "eval_metric" = "mlogloss",
              "num_class" = length(unique(gl_train$Type)))




cv.nround <- 5
cv.nfold <- 3

cvMod <- xgb.cv(param = param, data = train_gl,
                nfold = cv.nfold,
                nrounds = cv.nround,
                watchlist=watchlist)


#Build the Model
nrounds = 50
xgMod = xgboost(param = param, data = train_gl, nrounds = nrounds, watchlist = watchlist)
```

After executing xgMod i am getting the below mentioned error,

Error in check.custom.obj() : 
  Setting objectives in 'params' and 'obj' at the same time is not allowed

Let me know what's wrong in my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Mohan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is due to the `watchlist` parameter passed to `xgboost`.
`watchlist` is a parameter of `xgb.train` but not of `xgboost`, hence it is considered by `xgboost` like "other parameters" (`...`) .

The following code

```
xgMod <- xgboost(param = param, data = train_gl, nrounds = nrounds)
```

works correctly

```
[1]     train-mlogloss:1.259886 
[2]     train-mlogloss:0.963367 
[3]     train-mlogloss:0.755535 
[4]     train-mlogloss:0.601647 
[5]     train-mlogloss:0.478923
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the details